# How to convert void[] to U[]

Tags: typescript

I have this output [on the Playground](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/bJSPE5h0QULxJbvA?open=Program.ts&preview):

> [1, 2, 3]
>
> [undefined, undefined, undefined]

I just want to replace the second element with 5. This is my code:

Program.ts

```
import { Utils } from "./Utils";

class Program
{
    public static Main(): void
    {
        let array = [1, 2, 3];
        console.log(array);

        let array2 = Utils.ArrayModify(array, 1, 5);
        console.log(array2);
    }
}

Program.Main();
```

Units.ts

```
export class Utils
{
    public static ArrayModify<U>(array: U[], index: number, newValue: U)
    {
        return array.map((oldValue: U, currentIndex: number) =>
        {
            currentIndex === index ? newValue : oldValue;
        });
    }
}
```

**array.map** returns the void[] type but I need U[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to `return`:

`return currentIndex === index ? newValue : oldValue;`

Comment: Thanks! It works too: `return array.map((oldValue: U, currentIndex: number) =>
            currentIndex === index ? newValue : oldValue);`

Answer (score 0):

No return as mentioned in another post but also because arrays are just objects in javascript the above code can just be re-written to.

```
export class Utils
{
    public static ArrayModify<U>(array: U[], index: number, newValue: U): U[]
    {
        return Object.assign([], array, {[index]: newValue});
    }
}
```